# About JavaScript bind method

Tags: javascript, bind

[reference code segment](https://github.com/mattermost/platform/blob/556f2a93fbcbca0b81705145ce6150261d1861b0/webapp/components/root.jsx#L26)

```
this.localizationChanged = this.localizationChanged.bind(this);
```

Who can tell me why to write like that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: You should have searched "javascript bind".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Who can tell me why to write like that?

`localizationChanged` is used as event handler:

```
LocalizationStore.addChangeListener(this.localizationChanged);`
```

If the handler was not bound to the component instance, `this` would not refer to the component instance and it wouldn't be possible to call the `setState` method of the component (`this.setState(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access this in localizationChanged function you bind this.

However in ES2015 you don't require this.You can use arrow operator :

```
localizationChanged =()=>{
    console.log(this);
}
```